# Highslide popup problems in Internet Explorer

Tags: highslide

I designed a page with a Highslide gallery and thumbnail popups with secondard description popups, including controls.

When I check it in IE, the enlarged popup doesn't have any caption information (I commented out something to do with that in JS so I could do the second popup based on information from RoadRash).  The second thumbnail in the gallery is the one with the added popup and caption.  It works fine in Firefox and Safari, but not in IE.

I am by no means an expert in Javascript, but I would love to get this working.  Here's the [site](http://www.lorisboguedesigns.com/paulettelandersprototype/gallery_5.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some cleaning up before you can debug. Pull up your page in IE. Hit F12, then click Console. Refresh the page. This will identify script errors that are tripping up IE. One thing that catches my eye immediately is that you're trying to use HTML comments ( like `<!--this is a comment-->` ) in Javascript. That's not how you comment things out in Javascript.

Comment: See this link for how to create comments in JavaScript: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comments.asp